# Why my dictionary's outcomes are repetitive?

Tags: python-3.x

```
places = {
    'first_choice': 'bali',
    'second_choice': 'paris',
}

for choice, place in places.items():
    print(choice + " is " + place)
    print(choice + " is " + place)
```

As shown in the code above, I should get the following result:

```
second_choice is paris
first_choice is bali
```

But I get the following result:

```
second_choice is paris
second_choice is paris
first_choice is bali
first_choice is bali
```

May I know what goes wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, you're explicitly doing two identical `print`s for each dict entry. Why did you do that?

Comment: Because you have two print statements? What did you expect?

Comment: Ok, I get it~
just started to code, please forgive my silly mistake~

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you `print` the choice twice, so that is why your results are repeated. Using only one `print` should fix your problem.